# JSF <f:ajax execute with actionListener

Tags: java, jsf-2

Here is my Code which i am try in jsf 2.0 project.

1. `<h:input value="#{studentInfoBean.registrationFormNo}" id="registrationFormId"/>`
2. `<h:commandButton 
       type="submit"

       actionListener="# {studentInfoBean.searchStudentbyformNo}">

       <f:ajax execute="registrationFormId"   render="testlist" />

   </h:commandButton>`

when i enter a value in input field then click on commandButton so its give a result from the bean my bean name is studentInfobean SessionScoped. my question is that when input field is blank then click on commandbutton so bean is not called so i did not get any response my pervious result remain as it is.

Thanks

Comment: Use <h:messages/> to check whether a conversion or validation error occurs.

Comment: Hello Johny <h:message for="registrationFormId" style="color:red;" /> I use this one but no validation error same result

Comment: Can anybody help me out ?

Comment: Please add the code for your `searchStudentbyformNo` method. My take is that you didn't re-initiate the result objects when input is null of empty. Hence, the old result remains.

Comment: public String searchStudentbyformNo(){

final FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
HttpSession session = (HttpSession) facesContext.getExternalContext().getSession(false); 
System.out.println(" this.getRegistrationFormNo()--------->"+this.getRegistrationFormNo());
StudentRegistration studentRegistration = ServiceLocater.getStudentServices().getstudentregistrationFormNo(this.getRegistrationFormNo());

if(studentRegistration == null){
this.setMessageabc(" Record not found")
}
if(studentRegistration !=null){
this.setMessageabc("found");
}

return "";

}

Comment: I already check for null or empty but this.getRegistrationFormNo(); not giving null or empty this searchStudentbyFormNo method not at  all called by click on commandbutton

Comment: When Input field is blank

Comment: Please work through http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/hcommandlink-hcommandbutton-is-not-being-invoked/2120183#2120183